# A Link Adding Space in Content

Tags: css

Hi I have a content block which is spaced fine when I take out the a link, yet when the a link is in there there is a ton of spacing added (http://dev.liquor.com/wp-content/themes/main/sfgate/sfgate.php) - (http://www.ubuntu-pics.de/bild/98214/desk_1_071_0UK7d3.png).

Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated. I am noticing when I take the a link out in Firebug the content is spaced fine, however not so much when the a link is in there...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line breaks between the end of the span and the anchor.

Comment: i.e. have the span and the anchor on the same line

Answer (score 0):

NM I was able to put the more link inside my php function which is displaying the content and this works fine. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Set the font size on the body (or at least on a suitable parent element). There is a space between the anchor and the span which is inheriting the default font size from the browser, usually 16px unless the user has changed it.

It's good practice to set the font size on the body to avoid problems like this, and also to cut down on duplicate CSS declarations. You'll probably also find it better to use a relative unit for font-sizing, such as percent or em. There's a good explanation here: [CSS-discuss wiki on font size](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Font_Size)